# UITableView Exit Edit Mode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an array of objects which populate a `UITableView`. When a user removes the last object from the array, I automatically create a new "default" object. However, in the `TableView`, when the user gets there, the list is still in "Edit" mode. Is there a way for me to programatically set the `TableView` back to "normal" mode again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the table's `editing` property to `NO`. [UITableView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW59)