# exit edit mode and update nav bar items

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

With reference to this question: [Exit Edit Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311800/exit-edit-mode)

about exiting edit mode when the last row is being deleted, my question is - how do you update the navigation bar "edit" item? After deleting the last row, I'd like to remove this nav bar item altogether AND exit edit mode (which is done per the question below) AND revert this button status back to "Edit" (rather than "Done" which is its status after deleting the last row).

Thats what I am doing now:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


...


    if ([section count] == 0) { //last row in the section
        [listOfItems removeObject:accessNumbers];    //updating my data source 
         tblSimpleTable.editing = NO; //added per the question above 
 //         self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil; --> thats what ideally i would want to do
 //       [self setEditing:YES animated:YES]; --> adding this manually doen't help
    }
    else
    {
 ...
    }
}     


}
```

Thank you for the help!

UPDATE: adding this line doesn't help. I stil need to click on the nav bar item "Done" to exit the editing mode.

[self.tblSimpleTable setEditing:YES animated:YES];

if I also hide the nav bar item, I essentially can't exit the edit mode at all, and the screen is frozen (I have some other buttons on the view that simply dont react to touch anymore in that case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To leave editing mode, use this:

```
[self.tableview setEditing:NO animated:YES];
```

To remove the button all-together, use:

```
// Note that this only removes the right-most button.  If you want to remove all of the buttons on the right side, use rightBarButtonItems instead.
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

// If you want it animated, use:
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
```

Comment: Not working I am afraid...adding [self.tableview setEditing:NO animated:YES]; doesnt seem to leave edit mode - the screen is frozen (no other buttons are active). Remove the button from the nav bar works well, but then when i add a new row, the buttons reappear (as expected) but as "Done" and not as "Edit"

Comment: This looks correct to me, but with an incorrect triggering condition supplied by the original post.

Comment: I am pretty sure about the triggering - I get into this only when the last row was removed. Besides the problem that I have described, it all work out perfectly (nav bar item disappear after last row is being deleted, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

According to the apple documentation, you cannot call `[self.tableview setEditing:NO animated:YES]` from within your `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`. Here is the relevant excerpt:

> Note: The data source should not call `setEditing:animated:` from within its implementation of `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`. If for some reason it must, it should invoke it after a delay by using the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method.

Presumably one could then create a selector that turns off editing mode and removes the button.

Answer (score 3):

Can you enforce this rule in another callback?

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BOOL answer = [section count] > 1;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = (answer)? self.editButtonItem : nil;
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: it's being triggered. I am getting there. 100% positive.

Comment: I just remembered an older project where I had the same requirement.  Can you try the edit above?  In mine, I don't have a nav bar item, so that part I added in, but i do check my model count > 1 and do return the resulting bool and it works

Comment: Ok I found the problem...my seEditing was set to YES...@Inafzier was right.

Comment: np. thx.  glad it's working.  trying to prove you wrong about the trigger caused me to find a bug in my thing that i didn't know about, so thanks for the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues doing the same thing (not able to get the status of the barButtonItem to revert to 'Edit' after calling `setEditing`) and learned from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11490594/2888978 that the way to get change the 'Edit' back to 'Done' on the nave bar is to call `setEditing` on the view controller, not the table.  Then you can set the barButtonItem to `.None` to remove it from the nav bar when the table is empty.

So instead of calling:

```
self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```

You would call:

```
self.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```

Otherwise only the editing mode of the cells will change.