# UITableView setEditing to NO doesn't change barButtonItem back

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UITableViewController` inside of a `UINavigationController`. I am setting the `rightBarButtonItem` to the editing button:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

[image]

This works great, and after I call `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` I programmatically change my `tableView` out of editing mode using:

```
[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
```

The strange thing here is, the `barButtonItem` still seems to be in "edit mode" as it still says "Done" like it does when I am in editing mode.  Clicking it changes the button back to "Edit", then I have to click AGAIN to take it back into edit mode.

[image]

Why isn't the `barButtonItem` getting changed from editing mode as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The button controls the editing mode of the view controller, which is passing it onto the table view. You are taking the table view directly out of editing mode and not telling the view controller. Try setting the editing mode on `self` instead of `self.tableView`.

Comment: Ha, how, so simple yet I don't know if I would have realized what was causing it. Thank you so much!